# Local pointer to a global function

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, local, void-pointers

I want to use a local pointer to point to a global string. The pointer is a local pointer and the string is global. When I run this code passing the local pointer to the function "myfun" the pointer is not changed, i.e., its pointing address does not change. The values printed are "NULL".

Can someone tell me why this does not work on gcc?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *str[] = { "String #1", "Another string" };

void myfun( void * p, int i ) 
{ 
    p = ( void * ) &str[ i ][ 0 ]; 
}

int main( void ) 
{ 
    void * ptr1, * ptr2;

    myfun( ptr1, 0 ); 
    myfun( ptr2, 1 ); 
    printf( "%s\n%s\n", ptr1, ptr2 ); 
}
```

Comment: You start by telling us *how* it doesn't work.  What did you expect to happen?  What actually happened?

Comment: Fur the benefit of future readers, it'd be great if you edited this to include a description of what you mena by "doesn't work". Doesn't compile? Crashes? Executes but doesn't exhibit the behaviour you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a pointer, by value, to `myfun`. The value you assign to `p` in `myfun` is therefore not returned to the caller. You need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void myfun( void ** p, int i ) 
{ 
    *p = ( void * ) &str[ i ][ 0 ]; 
}
```

And call it like this:

```
myfun( &ptr1, 0 );
```

In fact you can write `myfun` like this:

```
void myfun( void ** p, int i ) 
{ 
    *p = str[i]; 
}
```

And in fact it would be simplest just to return the `void*` as the functions return value:

```
void *myfun( int i ) 
{ 
    return str[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you David Heffernan. Boths solutions worked fine. However this is just an example, actually I need to do this with more than one pointer, and return shall not work, so I have to pass the pointers as input argumenst. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your question isn't any different from -

```
void func(int i)
{
  i = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  printf("i = %d\n", i);
  func(i);
  printf("i = %d\n", i); /* Wonder why it doesn't output i = 2? */
}
```

In your code, you pass `ptr1` (and `ptr2`) arguments by value, change the value of the parameter `p` that you receive, and expect this change to be reflected on the argument that you passed.  That, that `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers doesn't change the fact that you are still passing by value.

Also, IANAL (i.e., I hope a language lawyer corrects me if I am wrong), but I think you are potentially headed for trouble by sending pointer to void variables as arguments to printf.